# How to read the arithmetic operators as input in python

Tags: python-3.x

How to take operator as input and how to perform operations using tat operator

I have tried using functions

If we provide the input `2,5,+`. the program should give output as 7.

Comment: Why java tag though?

Comment: Writing some code is a good start. Sharing this code and asking more specific questions a good next step after that. Please read: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you all of the code, but here's a good starting point.

In Python, check out the `operator` module:

```
>>> import operator
>>> sum = operator.add(2, 5)
>>> sum
7
>>> diff = operator.sub(2, 5)
>>> diff
-3
```